# ordinal variables and caret when preprocessing

Tags: r, r-caret

I have found that many examples in the APM book by Dr. Max Kuhn tend to cover data sets that have continuous variables as the predictor set. If working with a data set that has ordinal factors, would it make sense to turn these variables into dummy variables and lose the natural order of the variables? My question is motivated by the need to preprocess (ie, center, scale) the data set. I would like to know how others approach this in R?

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) than SO.

Comment: Agree it's not really a coding question, but would suggest _not_ turning into dummy variables as that will lose information. Better to coerce to numeric if the factors are 'ordered'.

Comment: My apologies. I had forgot to mention that I am interested in learning how to do this specifically in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the factor has class `ordered`, it will make linear combinations that support some level of polynomial. See [The Basics of Encoding Categorical Data for Predictive Models](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2013/10/23/the-basics-of-encoding-categorical-data-for-predictive-models) and `?ordered`. For example:

```
> pred2 <- ordered(letters[1:5])
> model.matrix(~pred2)

  (Intercept) pred2.L pred2.Q    pred2.C pred2^4
1           1 -0.6325  0.5345 -3.162e-01  0.1195
2           1 -0.3162 -0.2673  6.325e-01 -0.4781
3           1  0.0000 -0.5345 -4.096e-16  0.7171
4           1  0.3162 -0.2673 -6.325e-01 -0.4781
5           1  0.6325  0.5345  3.162e-01  0.1195
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$pred2
[1] "contr.poly"
```

Max

Comment: Can dummyVars handle ordered as well? Or should I just leave as ordered() and then model.matrix(), which should handle everything for me so that I can preProcess()? I don't quite understand the polynomial transformations...